# Uploading multiple files via Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

As known, each subsequent time that the FileReferenceList.browse() method is called, the FileReferenceList.fileList property is reset to the file(s) that the user selects in the dialog box. And my question is:

**How to manage to "remember" all previously selected files, each subsequent time that the FileReferenceList.browse() method is called?** so that to append new ones and upload them all later on.

Comment: You want the open file(s) dialog to have your previously chosen files to be already selected for you next time and from there on?

Comment: No, not that. I want to keep all previously selected files in memory and let user choose any extra files in case he forgot something... so that he wouldn't have to select all the files again. I hope I'm clear enough...

Comment: Do you think it's possible to copy FileReferenceList.fileList somewhere within the program and reuse it and then merge all the thing in one list? Something like a deep copy maybe?

Comment: Can't you just let the user select groups of files, upload them, and repeat the dialog as necessary? I mean it should not matter much whether your user uploads 20 files by uploading first 10 and then another 10, or whether he/she uploads 4 groups of 5 files each, or 20 files all at once. Right? Or am I missing something vitally important here?

Comment: My project's all about files, storage and the like. So I believe it would be an extra comfort to accomplish that.

Comment: BTW, how to not accomplish it I am able to figure out on my own. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The file reference list is just a collection of file references.   The file references are what you need in order to upload each file. (You don't need the FileReferenceList) You can simply copy all of the items to another collection.

If you are feeling adventurous and want to do it in an OO way you might try this:

- Create your own "AppendableFileReferenceList" which would extend FileReferenceList
- Every time a FileRefence list is created (i.e. .browse() is called ), the list returned is copied and appended to a separate collection in your object.
- You then have complete control over that collection.  (clearing it when you need etc.)

Depending on your needs you might even make that class take care of your uploading as well.